# Сбрасывается значение chronometer при смене ориентации

Tags: java, android

Я нашел на этот вопрос [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660965/how-to-contain-value-of-android-chronometer-with-change-in-orientation). Но я никак не могу понять как это использовать в моем случае, там `String` тип, а у меня `long`. В putString на второй аргумент `long` прописать не получиться...

Сам код:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    outState.putString("timerValue", timer);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details_layout);

    chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            long t = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
            chronometer.setText(DateFormat.format("mm:ss", t));
        }
    });
    chronometer.start();
}
```

**Правка:**

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    timer = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
    outState.putLong("timerValue", timer);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details_layout);

chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                timer = savedInstanceState.getLong("timerValue");
                chronometer.setText(DateFormat.format("mm:ss", timer));
            }
        });
        chronometer.start();
    } else {
        chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                timer = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
                chronometer.setText(DateFormat.format("mm:ss", timer));
            }
        });
        chronometer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно и в документацию посмотреть, [какие методы есть у класса `Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Bundle.html), а то, не дай бог, еще `int` придется туда положить, опять вся "разработка" встанет. Вы же не собираетесь за каждым неподходящим методом постить вопрос, так вы будете до второго пришествия "разрабатывать". И вообще разработка методом копипасты еще никого не сделала программистом, надо как то собственное умение развивать стараться, голову подключать что ли.

Comment: В том то и дело, что мне срочно нужно! А так, я знаю что нужно читать... Да и на счет Long конечно тупонул, я знал что есть getLong, getString и тд, просто туплю...

Comment: Посмотреть методы класса у вас бы заняло больше 15 минут, которые вы ждали ответ на этот вопрос ... Даже IDE сама предлагает все варианты, достаточно применить банальную логику, чтобы решить эту "проблему" за пару секунд, но у каждого свой путь, конечно, если особенно срочно нужно ..

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что использовать стоит

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
```

вместо

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)
```

`Bundle` помимо метода `putString()` имеет `putLong()` им и воспользуйтесь

Comment: Почему-то не хочет работать, посмотрите пожалуйста, обновил вопрос...

Comment: @Omuradil, дебажить код вам придется самому.

Comment: Не очень понял...